# Max Value for MSAccess Date/Time

Tags: ms-access

What is the largest (latest) date that can be represented in Microsoft Access?

Comment: Is your Google broken or what?

Comment: Search on specifications in Access help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/601315-vba-data-types, it's December 31, 9999.

Answer (score 5):

> [Valid date values range from -657,434 (January 1, 100 A.D.) to 2,958,465 (December 31, 9999 A.D.). Valid time values range from 0.0 to 0.9999, or 23:59:59.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA100963211033.aspx)